# Do i need voltage stabilisers for Computers and other electronic devices without motor?

Tags: voltage, surge-protection

Searching on internet i've found this article

https://www.bijlibachao.com/appliances/voltage-stabilizer-for-television-refrigerator-air-conditioner.html

Where i've read that electronic devices and in general appliances without motor does not need voltage regulators.
This seems very strange for me because until now i was believing that my computer , TV , DVD player , satellite Receiver..etc need voltage regulators and i have this because what if grid voltage goes 320V or more in some situations ?

So , do i really need a voltage stabilizers  for electronic devices ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sorry, but per the [help/on-topic], this question is off topic. Please read [help/on-topic] to better understand what is acceptable to ask here.

Comment: It considerably depends on the region of the world in which you are living. In the part of Europe in which I am living we commonly do not have those critical fluctuations.

Comment: @daniel.neumann I mean when there are these critical fluctuations , because the article claim that we don't need at all voltage regulators for electronic devices that doesn't have motors.

Comment: @CharlieRB Sorry , but if you can watch my previous questions , i have this :http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223583/what-will-change-with-my-new-inverter?noredirect=1#comment481872_223583 , and i've made this questions to electronics forum , but someone has migrated to SuperUser forum..And that question has a similar topic with my actual question. Really i don't understand where should i make the actual question. It seems that people here are confusing new users , and of course are ready for down votes.

Comment: Sorry. I can understand your frustration with being bounced around. Please understand that your question is regionally specific to your locale. We could not possibly know about these things if we are from a different country. Where I live, those things are not needed in most home. Maybe if you [edit] you question to be more clear about what you are asking related to computers, then it will be more on-topic, and someone will help you.

Comment: I don't think that voltage fluctuations are located only to a specific country. When an electrical grid has a problem that may happen for 100+ reasons , of course at one country can happen every month , on another country once a year  and on other countries oncer in 2-3 years. But this does not make my question off-topic. When a  fluctuation happen , does the electronic devices like computer , TV , .etc may be damaged ? The article that i've posted above say no , but i'm not really convinced  so i;ve asked here.

Comment: As i'm a new user , at least someone will help me and transfer my question to the correct forum. Thank you !

Comment: I think, that the electrics.se was a good choice in the first place. Not sure why your first question was migrated. I have to correct  myself: You are right. We have these fluctuations. However, they are rare and, hence, most people that I know do not care (I my fathers office they once lost a computer because of a lightning that hit a power pylon nearby.). Actually, I would argue that it is a question of personal taste whether one takes the change or not that his/her device is damaged by voltage fluctuations.

Comment: @daniel.neumann Ok , but for your personal opinion , do you agree with the explanations and the conclusions on that article that i've posted on my post ?

Comment: If your trying to protect your computer (on topic for here) a full featured UPS can do regulation as needed, and some protection, and blackout and brownout protection. It could be said that it is not required , but who cares what they say, a Good UPS can prevent and stabalise. a Cheap UPS could be made to protect only from blackout and minor surge protect, so potentially could advantage from seperated regulation, with a cheap UPS. If your trying to protect and stablise your computer power, research UPSes for computers that are (way more) full featured.

Comment: As far as the validity of the statements made , the artical title represents itself as a "consumption" artical not protection, and some of the statements made in it could be (lets say) improved.

Comment: As far as computers, the power supply will handle a certain range of voltages, which will be on a label on the power supply.  If the voltage is within that range, you don't necessarily need a voltage regulator.  Outside of that range, the power supply can be damaged if the voltage is too high or if there are surges, and your computer will shut off unexpectedly, likely causing corruption, if the voltage is too low, even momentarily.  If you live in an area where the voltage, even periodically, is outside the range specified for the power supply, get a UPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your question applies to electrical appliances everywhere in the world.  That article is accurate about voltage variations that are problematic for motorized appliances and irrelevant to electronics.  Appliances have voltage ratings for continuous operation.  Wider numbers apply for intermittent voltages.  For example, properly designed electronics (even before PCs existed) would routinely withstand up to 600 volts without damage.  Today's electronics are typically more robust.

Motorized appliances may be at greater risk due to voltage anomalies.  And not just due to voltage variation.  Other anomalies created by a UPS in battery backup mode can create problems for motorized appliances. That same 'dirty' power is perfectly good for electronics.

UPS provides temporary and 'dirty' power during blackouts - so that unsaved data can be saved.  It does nothing for electronic hardware protection, does not claim to, and can be problematic for life expectancy of motorized appliances.

Numbers for those trends vary based upon 120 or 230 volt operation, time, and other factors.  But that article is quite accurate.  It contradicts many who are only educated by hearsay and advertising.  UPS does almost nothing for protection of electronic hardware.  Otherwise one could provide numbers for each electronic part that is harmed without a UPS.

You concern is a rare anomaly, maybe once every seven years, that might overwhelm robust protection already inside every appliance.  That solution is provided by something completely different.